# Need JavaScript help. dropdown menu issue

Tags: javascript, html

can you please run the snippet and see my issue. All I need is to fix arrows to work correct. Right now everything is good when clicking the same element to open and close the drop down. But if you try to open the drop down clicking on first element then click on second element the first drop down will close but arrow will remain how it was in open position.

```js
function toggleClass(element, className) {
  if (!element || !className) {
    return;
  }

  var classString = element.className,
    nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
  if (nameIndex == -1) {
    classString += ' ' + className;
  } else {
    classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex + className.length);
  }
  element.className = classString;
}

function dropDown(el) {

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.overlayOpen'))
    .filter(elem => elem !== el.nextElementSibling)
    .forEach(element => element.classList.remove('overlayOpen'));

  toggleClass(el.nextElementSibling, 'overlayOpen');
  toggleClass(el, 'listPoints');
  toggleClass(el, 'arrUp');
}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.overlayOpen {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
}
.arrUp::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-top: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  border-right: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.listPoints::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 7px;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-top: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  border-right: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="1" class="listPoints" onclick='dropDown(this)'>example</li>
  <li id="overlay_1" class='overlay'>Hidden stuff</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li id="2" class="listPoints" onclick='dropDown(this)'>example</li>
  <li id="overlay_2" class='overlay'>Hidden stuff</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: If you're using arrow functions, why not also use `.classList.toggle`?

Comment: It's because your code has no sense of "others" only "self". In other words, the arrow will only change direction when it's parent is clicked, not if another is clicked.

Comment: Please check my answer :)

Comment: I know you are super professional guys, and I'm very new with JS and surely my code is very bad, sometimes happens things like this when you just need some solution and not a perfect code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a big fan of your style, but if you have to do it this way, then you need to reverse all of the effects of "opening" the dropdown when another is opened :

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.overlayOpen'))
    .filter(elem => elem !== el.nextElementSibling)
    .forEach(element => {element.classList.remove('overlayOpen'); 
            element.previousElementSibling.classList.remove('arrUp');
            element.previousElementSibling.classList.add('listPoints');
    })
```

Comment: You can even remove `.filter` and process in `forEach`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/4s10uowe/)

Answer (score 0):

Fix by removing or comming this line of code

```
.forEach(element => element.classList.remove('overlayOpen'));
```

see the updated code below

```js
function toggleClass(element, className) {
  if (!element || !className) {
    return;
  }

  var classString = element.className,
    nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
  if (nameIndex == -1) {
    classString += ' ' + className;
  } else {
    classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex + className.length);
  }
  element.className = classString;
}

function dropDown(el) {

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.overlayOpen'))
    .filter(elem => elem !== el.nextElementSibling)
   // .forEach(element => element.classList.remove('overlayOpen'));

  toggleClass(el.nextElementSibling, 'overlayOpen');
  toggleClass(el, 'listPoints');
  toggleClass(el, 'arrUp');
}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
}
li {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.overlayOpen {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 800px;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  -ms-transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
  transition: height 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease;
}
.arrUp::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-top: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  border-right: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.listPoints::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 7px;
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-top: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  border-right: 0.3em solid #A0A09F;
  -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="1" class="listPoints" onclick='dropDown(this)'>example</li>
  <li id="overlay_1" class='overlay'>Hidden stuff</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li id="2" class="listPoints" onclick='dropDown(this)'>example</li>
  <li id="overlay_2" class='overlay'>Hidden stuff</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Allan, It's not working. On clicking second element first drop down not closing